# Using OCR to convert a spreadsheet image to data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tesseract

I'm try to convert the data in an image to a data frame in R using tesseract, but have run into a problem, perhaps due to my use of regular expressions.

```
library(magick)
library(tesseract)

team_img <- image_read("measuring.png")

 team_mgk <- team_img %>%
  image_resize('2000x') %>%
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
  image_trim(fuzz = 40) %>%
  image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
  tesseract::ocr()
 
 cat(team_mgk)
 
 text1_a <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', team_mgk)

 read.table(text=team_mgk, 
            col.names=c('Time_factor', 'Tree_#', 'Species', 
                        'Fragment','Linear_Extension', 'Colur'))

 # Error
 # Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
 # dec = dec,  : 
 # line 1 did not have 6 elements
```

The idea is learn how to use OCR to read in a data frame. The image is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The OCR did a good job, with only a single underscore missing in the last row which causes `read.table` to throw an error. This can be fixed with simple replacement using `sub`.

Since the image is online now at https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9lWV.png after being uploaded in your question, we can create a fully reproducible example.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magick)
library(tesseract)

df <- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9lWV.png" %>%
  image_read() %>%
  image_resize('2000x') %>%
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
  image_trim(fuzz = 40) %>%
  image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
  tesseract::ocr() %>%
  strsplit('\n') %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  `[`(-1) %>%
  {sub('Time 2', 'Time_2', .)} %>%
  {read.table(text = .)} %>%
  setNames(c('Time_factor', 'Tree #', 'Species', 'Fragment', 
             'Linear Extension(mm)', 'Colour'))
```

Resulting in

```r
df
#>    Time_factor Tree #  Species Fragment Linear Extension(mm) Colour
#> 1       Time_O     31 A.tenius      12A                49.50  Brown
#> 2       Time_1     31 A.tenius      12A                56.72  Brown
#> 3       Time_2     31 A.tenius      12A                74.38  Brown
#> 4       Time_O     31 A.tenius      12B                58.66  Brown
#> 5       Time_1     31 A.tenius      12B                78.45  Brown
#> 6       Time_2     31 A.tenius      12B                94.37  Brown
#> 7       Time_O     31 A.tenius      12C                55.97  Brown
#> 8       Time_1     31 A.tenius      12C                90.12  Brown
#> 9       Time_2     31 A.tenius      12C               121.61  Brown
#> 10      Time_O     31 A.tenius      12D                70.19  Brown
#> 11      Time_1     31 A.tenius      12D                91.82  Brown
#> 12      Time_2     31 A.tenius      12D               115.57  Brown
#> 13      Time_O     34 A.tenius       3B                60.10 Yellow
#> 14      Time_1     34 A.tenius       3B                79.00 Yellow
#> 15      Time_2     34 A.tenius       3B               103.82 Yellow
#> 16      Time_O     34 A.tenius       3C                48.18 Yellow
#> 17      Time_1     34 A.tenius       3C                58.70 Yellow
#> 18      Time_2     34 A.tenius       3C                99.03 Yellow
#> 19      Time_O     34 A.tenius       3D                66.12 Yellow
#> 20      Time_1     34 A.tenius       3D                84.05 Yellow
#> 21      Time_2     34 A.tenius       3D               114.38 Yellow
#> 22      Time_O     34 A.tenius       3E                68.94 Yellow
#> 23      Time_1     34 A.tenius       3E                92.30 Yellow
#> 24      Time_2     34 A.tenius       3E               109.05 Yellow
#> 25      Time_O     34 A.tenius       4A                46.20   Blue
#> 26      Time_1     34 A.tenius       4A                67.00   Blue
#> 27      Time_2     34 A.tenius       4A               127.48   Blue
#> 28      Time_O     34 A.tenius       4B                87.19   Blue
#> 29      Time_1     34 A.tenius       4B               109.18   Blue
#> 30      Time_2     34 A.tenius       4B               109.71   Blue
#> 31      Time_O     34 A.tenius       4C                77.26   Blue
#> 32      Time_1     34 A.tenius       4C               123.57   Blue
#> 33      Time_2     34 A.tenius       4C               135.59   Blue
#> 34      Time_O     34 A.tenius       4D                60.01   Blue
#> 35      Time_1     34 A.tenius       4D                80.32   Blue
#> 36      Time_2     34 A.tenius       4D               101.75   Blue
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can this approach work for example if I have an image with a captcha code on it? I see all data was perfectly extracted but could it work for the captcha?

Comment: @user007 you could try, but the whole point of captcha is to make text that is readable by humans and not by OCR, so I very much doubt it. If tesseract can read it, the captcha isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: It actually reads but always fail a letter or number, accuracy is always 80%